# DIV:hover, 3 Shown, 3 Hidden, 1 Headline

Tags: html, css

I have 3 "main" boxes labeled #box1, #box2, & #box3. Hovering over any one of the boxes is supposed to unhide its respective "hidden" information text, labeled .info1, .info2, .info3. At the same time it is supposed to chang the opacity of the other boxes to 0.2 and hide ".headline".

I'm trying to avoid Javascript, so I'm trying to do it with CSS.

I have looked around and found multiple topics on it but I can't wrap my head around why this does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/q6jpjz65/1/

```
    .headline {
        display: block;
    }
    .info1 {
        display: none;
    }
    .info2 {
        display: none;
    }
    .info3 {
        display: none;
    }



    #box1, #box2, #box3 { 
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
        width: 1.92708%; 
        height: 3.7871%;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid white;
        outline: 1px solid black;
        opacity: 1;
    }



    #box1:hover #box2 #box3 {
        opacity: 0.2; 
    }
    #box1:hover + .info1 {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #box1:hover + .headline {
        display: none;
        opacity: 1; 
    }


    #box2:hover #box1 #box3 {
        opacity: 0.2; 
    }
    #box2:hover + .info2 {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #box2:hover + .headline {
        display: none;
        opacity: 1; 
    }



    #box3:hover #box1 #box2 {
        opacity: 0.2; 
    }
    #box3:hover + .info3 {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #box3:hover + .headline {
        display: none;
        opacity: 1; 
    }


    <div class="headline">
    This text is always displayed when nothing is hovered.
    </div>
    <div id="box1" style="top: 10%">
        <div class="info1">
        Information for box1.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" style="top: 30%">
        <div class="info2">
        Information for box2.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box3" style="top: 50%">
        <div class="info3">
        Information for box3.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot use css hover events to add styles to previous elements in the dom. You will need JS to achieve this.

Comment: Why does this work though? I tried to do something similar to this, I'm just not working with ul/li: http://jsfiddle.net/165Laav6/

Comment: Because that is changing the `ul` based on its parent hover. Then it gives the hovered `li` its own specific style. You could do something similar, but you cannot hide the text unless you want to hide the text even if its hovered as well.

Comment: I see...ok, well thank you! I will go search google for implementing javascript into Spencer's edit below http://stackoverflow.com/a/32448942/5274135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try wrapping everything in a `wrap` div and styling based on that: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6jpjz65/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="headline">This text is always displayed when nothing is hovered.    
  </div>
  <div id="box1" style="top: 10%">
    <div class="info1">Information for box1.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box2" style="top: 30%">
    <div class="info2">Information for box2.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box3" style="top: 50%">
    <div class="info3">Information for box3.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap:hover #box2, .wrap:hover #box3, .wrap:hover #box1{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.wrap:hover .headline {display: none;}
#box1:hover, #box2:hover, #box3:hover {opacity: 1 !important;}
```

The main issue you will have without JS is that to hide the Headline, it will also hide if you hover over the headline since it has to be wrapped inside the element to which the hover event is applied.

Javascript is recommended.

Comment: This definitely answered my question, and thank you for explaining why I need javascript (you predicted that I don't want the header to hide on hover lol). I ended up using the JS from Spencer's post. THANK YOU BOTH! http://stackoverflow.com/a/32448942/5274135

Comment: Good deal. Be sure to upvote his answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For showing the child elements you just need to remove the `+` in the CSS, from `#box1:hover + .info1` to just `#box1:hover .info1`:

```
#box1:hover .info1 { ... }

#box2:hover .info2 { ... }

#box3:hover .info3 { ... }
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6jpjz65/2/)

But for changing the opacity of other boxes to `0.2` and hiding `.headline` you will need to use JavaScript. Here is how it would look for `#box1`:

```
document.getElementById("box1").onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "none";
    for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
        if(i != 1) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.2";
    }
}
```

Although you could leave the styling of other boxes in pure CSS by doing wrapper as noted in **@dwreck08** answer. So that JS could be simplified to just (for all boxes):

```
for(var j=1; j<4; j++) {
    document.getElementById("box"+j).onmouseover = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

If you need the headline to reappear `onmouseout` you would do:

```
for(var j=1; j<4; j++) {
    document.getElementById("box"+j).onmouseover = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("box"+j).onmouseout = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "block";
    }    
}
```

*Note this can be greatly simplified using JS libraries like jQuery*

Comment: This is incomplete answer: `At the same time it is supposed to changed the opacity of the other boxes to 0.2 and hide ".headline".`

Comment: Saved me a TON of time googling! This fully fixed my code. THANK YOU!!